# visual studio 2010 web projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

This is just taking too long. Cannot install visual studio, i have a msdn subscription, but after installing the grand total of available web projects is 3. mvc won't install. sp1 won't install. any ideas? win xp. this is driving me nuts. why can't it "just work"?

since it won't let me invent tags, i'll include them here: i-give-up wtf-microsoft

Comment: For a lot of people it does "just work". If you're having problems, please be detailed with the problems you're having. Simply saying "won't install" doesn't give anyone much of a starting point to help you.

Comment: screen shot

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/206028/projectScreen.png

Comment: error logs http://dl.dropbox.com/u/206028/Microsoft%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Tools%20Update_20110524_102327704-MSI_AspNetWebPages.msi.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem with backslashes. http://forums.asp.net/t/1661809.aspx/1 . Hope this will help someone else